# Using Simple Membership Provider with mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to use Simple Membership Provider with mysql(also using Entity Framework)

If yes, how to achieve it.

Any documentation/link is really appreciated

Thank in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I create MySqlSimpleMembershipProvider on GitHub and make sample projects.

https://github.com/xyz37/MySqlSimpleMembershipProvider

That's all.

Thank you for the answer to this question.

Click to sample screenshot : https://raw.github.com/xyz37/MySqlSimpleMembershipProvider/master/_ScreenShot/SimpleMembershipProviderTest.png

Comment: This is the answer I have just used  Kim's application and it works

Comment: @Kim Ki Won, I've tried adding the extensions to my project with limited success.  The biggest problem is the DB context.  You have a `UserProfile` class in the MySql.Web.Extension project that's very similar to the partial class `UserProfile` that comes with the MVC4 template.  Why is that?

Answer (score 4):

Check this brief article from Fabio Costa on how to use SimpleMembership and OAuth with mySQL and bigint or any database and datatype you want: http://fabiocosta.ca/2012/11/24/use-simplemembership-and-oauth-with-any-database-and-datatype/. It should solve your problem. Good luck.

I also did following changes to my code:

- Added references to MySql.Data, MySql.Data.Entity and MySql.Web. Modified property 'Copy Local' to true on each reference.
- Changed connectionstring and added DbProviderFactory in web.config to enable MySql connections.
- Added roleManager and memberShip configuration in web.config.

web.config

```
<connectionStrings>    
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Database=dbname;User ID=username;Password=password;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <clear />
        <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="simple">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <membership defaultProvider="simple">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
</system.web>
```

- Created _AppStart.cshtml in root to initialize db connection and autom. create tables in db upon application startup.

_AppStart.cshtml

```
@{
    if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
    }
}
```

- Added filter to ensure db connection during authentication requests. This is the same as manually placing the InitializeSimpleMembership attribute on each controller.

App_Start\FilterConfig.cs

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute());
    }
}
```

- Then got my oAuth fixed with facebook following this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc

Comment: http://fabiocanada.ca/2012/11/24/use-simplemembership-and-oauth-with-any-database-and-datatype/ link is not working :(

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.

`SimpleMembershipProvider` is ultimately just a derived class of the good, old `MembershipProvider` that we all love and hate.

It's there because people didn't like just how many abstract functions you'd have to override to get a custom `MembershipProvider` working. So this is a very much dumbed-down implementation of `MembershipProvider`. You'd have to go back re-override the implementations for these functions with `SimpleMembershipProvider`.

I had the same question about modifying the DB design, had to go back to a custom `MembershipProvider` class.

Also, taken from Microsoft employee/ASP.NET developer [John Galloway's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx):

> While SimpleMembership is not database agnostic, it works across the
>   SQL Server family. It continues to support full SQL Server, but it
>   also works with SQL Azure, SQL Server CE, SQL Server Express, and
>   LocalDB. Everything's implemented as SQL calls rather than requiring
>   stored procedures, views, agents, and change notifications.
>
> Note that SimpleMembership still requires some flavor of SQL Server -
>   it won't work with MySQL, NoSQL databases, etc. You can take a look at
>   the code in WebMatrix.WebData.dll using a tool like ILSpy if you'd
>   like to see why - there are places where SQL Server specific SQL
>   statements are being executed, especially when creating and
>   initializing tables. It seems like you might be able to work with
>   another database if you created the tables separately, but I haven't
>   tried it and it's not supported at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing it by using LLBLGen (which works for MySql, Oracle, Firebird, DB2, and more): [SimpleMembershipProvider in MVC4 for MySql, Oracle, and more with LLBLGen](http://www.mattjcowan.com/funcoding/2012/11/10/simplemembershipprovider-in-mvc4-for-mysql-oracle-and-more-with-llblgen/).

You could do the same as described in this article by creating your own implementation of the ExtendedMembershipProvider with whatever DAL strategy you want. If you want to use Entity Framework, you'll code your provider implementation with a MySql provider that supports the Entity Framework (see: [DevArt's MySql Entity Framework Tutorial](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/articles/tutorial_ef.html)).

Answer (score 1):

There is surprisingly very few providers out there and seems like none for MySQL which is really sad.
It would seem to be easy to override the SimpleMemberShip Provider to work with MySQL but I can't find anyone who made a working package for this.

I did however find a package for MonogDB which looks ok (didn't test it though)
http://extmongomembership.codeplex.com/

We can only hope that MySQL will support this in future - although I doubt it as there is no announcements about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes  Just visit https://github.com/xyz37/MySqlSimpleMembershipProvider

Download the sample application  and modify to your needs.  It works great out of the box. When you run the application for the first time after crating user  and appropriate permissions if you get an error that database could not be created, refresh browser once or twice and it will create the database.

Answer (score 0):

There's an upgraded one of the accepted answer, at https://mysqlmembershipprovider.codeplex.com/, which is based on xyz37's works and ASP.NET Web Stack.