# Membership.Provider for mysql in asp.net issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, visual-studio-2010, razor

Using MVC4 synced to a mysql server.  Did it successfully by changing the machine.config and successfully used the ASP.net Configuration Tool to create users.  However when I log in with a username that I created using the tool (and is in the database) I get this error

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
Message=To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider".
Source=WebMatrix.WebData
StackTrace:
   at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.VerifyProvider()
   at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Login(String userName, String password, Boolean persistCookie)
   at KHSWebsite.Controllers.AccountController.Login(LoginModel model, String returnUrl) in c:\users\alex\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\KHSWebsite\KHSWebsite\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 38
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
InnerException:
```

This is a fresh database with a fresh MVC4 Razor web site from VS2010.  Any thoughts?

UPDATE: 
Here is my Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <configSections>
   <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
 </configSections>
 <connectionStrings>
   <remove name="LocalMySqlServer"/>
   <add name="LocalMySqlServer"
     connectionString="Datasource=localhost;Database=KHS;uid=root;pwd=power1739;"
     providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
 <appSettings>
   <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
   <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
   <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
   <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
   <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true" />
 </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider"/>
    <membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
     <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
     </namespaces>
   </pages>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
</entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you seen the following: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/security/16-adding-security-and-membership ?  Look for the section that begins: _"Note: If you see an error that tells you that a property must be an instance of ExtendedMembershipProvider"_  Hope that helps.

Comment: ...and some additional troubleshooting details that might be helpful can be found here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/d352bb1b-577c-42b7-8872-5ed59cd65f32/

Comment: still no good, tried it but same error

Comment: have you looked at this thread? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620922/using-simple-membership-provider-with-mysql

Comment: No need for that as the databases were built successfully using the asp.net configuration tool in VS2010.

Comment: Look at [this](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/02/how-to-setup-and-configure-mysql-membership-provider-6-2-2-porting-to-mono-part-2-of-3/)

Comment: A bit of off topic but I'd recommend looking at [Memflex](https://github.com/OdeToCode/Memflex) which is far more extensible membership/role provider. Further reading [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/10/01/build-your-own-membership-system-for-asp-net-mvc-part.aspx) and [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/10/02/build-your-own-membership-system-for-asp-net-mvc-part-again.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asp.Net MVC simple membership is not the same as normal web forms Membership provider. Check following [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx). From linked article

- SimpleMembership integrates with the previous membership system, but you can't use a MembershipProvider with SimpleMembership
- ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms does not use SimpleMembership; it implements OAuth on top of ASP.NET Membership

See also following image:
[image: Membership Provider Class Diagram]

From exception, it is understood that your provider is [classic membership provider](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-tutorials-asp-roles.html) and it is not compatible with Simple Membership.

```
"Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider".
```

You can look to following [post1](http://fabiocanada.ca/2012/11/24/use-simplemembership-and-oauth-with-any-database-and-datatype/),[post2](http://fabiocanada.ca/2012/11/24/use-simplemembership-and-oauth-with-any-database-and-datatype/)  for MySql compatible Asp.Net MVC Simple Membership provider.

Answer (score 2):

You define `defaultProvider` for `roleManager` and `membership` but you must also add providers for them. like this

```
    <membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider"
                  type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, mysql.web"
                    connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer"
                    enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
                    enablePasswordReset="true"
                    requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
                    requiresUniqueEmail="true"
                    passwordFormat="Hashed"
                    maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
                    minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
                    minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
                    passwordAttemptWindow="10"

                    applicationName="/"
                    autogenerateschema="true"/>
        </providers>
    </membership>

    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySqlRoleProvider">
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer"
                applicationName="/"
                name="MySqlRoleProvider"
                type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, mysql.web"
                autogenerateschema="true"/>
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-tutorials-asp-roles.html) for more information.