# Configure ASP.NET MVC 4 Application with Oracle Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, oracle11gr2

I am currently working on ASP.NET MVC 4 project with Oracle database. I have successfully add the connection string in my Web.config file like here:

```
<add name="OracleDBConnString" connectionString="Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=ISDQA;User ID=isd;Password=isdqa;" providerName="System.Data.OleDB" />
```

But when I create a new project, it has already have a built-in authentication classes. How can I modify these classes once and for all? **I want to change the default `ConnString`**.

Here's my model:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("OracleDBConnString")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}

public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my User controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    //I WANT TO MODIFY THIS PART
    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe)) 
    {

        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
}
```

**UPDATE**

When I change the `base("DefaultConnection")` to `base("OracleDBConnString")`, I got this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

A null was returned after calling the 'get_ProviderFactory' method on a store provider instance of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection'. The store provider might not be functioning correctly.
```

Note that I already added `using System.Data.OleDb;` on my usings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of creating special class you can setup in web.config which membership provider you use.

For Oracle there exist an `OracleMembershipProvider` class, which you can find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10928_01/OracleMembershipProviderClass.htm).
For MySQL you can use `MySQLMembershipProvider`. There is a nice article how you can setup it: [How to Setup and Configure MySql Membership Provider](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/02/how-to-setup-and-configure-mysql-membership-provider-6-2-2-porting-to-mono-part-2-of-3/)

Moreover you can use [Entity Framework Code First Membership Provider](http://codefirstmembership.codeplex.com/)  and use proper provider (look on this article: [Entity Framework Code-First support for Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite](http://blogs.devart.com/dotconnect/entity-framework-code-first-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-and-sqlite.html)). I did not try this solution, but it looks promising.

If nothing above helps you can write your own Memebership provider, but I am sure that you can find something which already exists.

To sum up: Instead of changing connection type, change membership provider which will be specific for your needs. Your code shouldn't notice change, because every membership provider inherits base `MemebershipProivder` class

Comment: I don't get it. Do I have to change the connection string?

Comment: By the way I installed the CodeFirst Membership Provider.

Comment: @garath Can you explain me how to set Oracle MemberShip provider Look to my Answer over here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094959/using-oracle-membership-provider-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

Asp.Net SimpleMembership and Asp.Net Membership are different beasts, I am afraid. Asp.Net MVC4 templates use SimpleMembership (WebSecurity.Login).

See my answer about MySql Membership provider usage in Asp.Net MVC4 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16779906/41782). Simply changing connection string or other things will not help you. You need to find an Oracle Asp.Net SimpleMembership or write your own.